# NetworkOnMainThreadException with URL().readText() in kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, url, kotlin

I'm working in android studio, and am using kotlin coroutines to retrieve results from an API.

I need to wait til the coroutine is finished, so I can assign a global variable from it.

I've tested the URL and it's OK.
I've tried regular threads, which works, but am not able to make the main thread wait for it to finish.

I tried with Fuel.get() and it worked fine, but would like to use URL().

```
var response = "";
val req = "url.com"
runBlocking { launch {
            response = URL(req).readText()
} }
```

Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work? It throws an NetworkOnMainThreadException, but it's wrapped in a coroutine.

Comment: `readText()` may not be a `suspend` function. You have not indicated what thread you want the coroutine to use. `runBlocking` will freeze the UI, even if you do the network I/O on a background thread. And I recommend using some newer, more robust HTTPS client API than `java.net.URL`.

Comment: You should do this in a `ViewModel` using `viewModelScope` for automatic background scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Ended up using a `AsyncTask` to read from URL, and a `Handler` to schedule handling the results.

```
var response = ""

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
inner class Retriever : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
      override fun doInBackground(vararg args : String?): String {
            val urlRequest = args[0].toString()
            var urlResponse = "";

            //Try to extract url
            try {
                urlResponse = URL(urlRequest).readText()
                println("SUCCESS in Retrieve.")
            } catch (e : Exception) {
                println("EXCEPTION in Retrieve.")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return urlResponse;
        }

        //Assigns value to response
        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            response = result.toString() //Result possibly void type
    }
}

override fun onCreate() {
    Retriever().execute("url.com")
    Handler().{/*Handle response here*/, 10000)
}
```

Comment: AsyncTask is deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: The book Android Studio Development Essentials (4.2 or newer) explained every well about creating a child.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var response = "";
val req = "url.com"
runBlocking<Unit> { 
GlobalScope.launch {
    response = URL(req).readText()
}
    //Work with the response here
}
```

You can preview all coroutine documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html)

Comment: I tried, and ```response``` is still not assigned within the ```runBlocking``` clause.

Comment: You still experience the NetworkOnMainThreadException? Or it's just the `response` that is not assigned?

Comment: Just that response is not assigned, fixed the exception tho!

Comment: Is `GlobalScope` recommended to use in Android?  How do you cancel this scope when a fragment destroys.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want handle the result of `URL(req).readText()` in another thread,do as following codes.

```
var response = "";
val req = "url.com"
runBlocking<Unit> { 
GlobalScope.launch {
    response = URL(req).readText()
    //here is another thread,handle response here
}
 //here is main thread, you can't get the result of URL(req).readText() because io operation need a long time .

}
```

If you handle the result in the main thread , please use Hanlder class

Answer (score 0):

For me the below code works smoothly.

```
var response = "";
val req = "yoururl.com"
runBlocking {    
 try {
  withTimeout(5000) {  // 5 seconds for timeout
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {    // using IO Dispatcher and not the default
     response = URL(req).readText()
    } // launch
  } // timeout
 } catch (e:Exception) {  // Timeout, permission, URL or network error
   response="Error"   // Here one uses a not valid message
 }
 // Here one manages 'response' variable for error handling or valid output.
```

It's also important add the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside main `manifest` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

An advantage of this type of approach (for tasks that are not too long ) is simplicity because it does not require the use of a `callback` routine, since it is a sequential code.